# CFLDAP to delete a group in memberOf

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, cfml

Can anyone help me on how to delete a group in memberOf in AD? Is this correct?

```
<cffunction name="deleteMemberOfLDAPGroup" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="UserDN" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="GroupDN" required="true" type="string" /> 
    <cfldap action="modify" 
        modifytype="delete"             
        attributes="member=#arguments.UserDN#" 
        dn="#arguments.GroupDN#" 
        separator="|"
        server = "myserver.com" 
        port="389"
        username="testuser"
        password="abc123" />    
</cffunction>
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you tried it what happened?

Comment: Someone has flagged this for closure as "unclear what you're asking". It's completely clear what's being asked here: "Can anyone help me on how to delete a group in memberOf in AD". Which part of that is not clear? [boggle]